# Problems occur when looping a flow with authentication in BotFramework

Tags: c#, oauth, botframework

The bot is assembled using the sample code of BotFramework v4.

It is a waterfall format and I want to go back to the previous step and continue the flow, but I cannot continue the flow.

After performing OAuth authentication with BotFramework, if you try to return to the previous flow, an error will occur after processing the previous step.

The details of the error are as follows:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter:Error: [OnTurnError] unhandled error : The given key 'stepIndex' was not present in the dictionary.  

System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'stepIndex' was not present in the dictionary.
```

Dialog has the following flow.
zero: Authenticate
→ one: Confirm authentication and perform flow
→ two: Return to one
→ one: Continue the flow.

The code is as follows.

```
public MainDialog(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
            : base(nameof(MainDialog), configuration["ConnectionName"])
        {
            _logger = logger;

            AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
                nameof(OAuthPrompt),
                new OAuthPromptSettings
                {
                    ConnectionName = ConnectionName,
                    Text = "Please login",
                    Title = "Login",
                    Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
                }));

            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                zero,
                one,
                two,
                three
            }));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> zero(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> one(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
            if (tokenResponse != null)
            {
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"one:You are now logged in.") }, cancellationToken);
            }

            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful please try again."), cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> two(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var result = (string)stepContext.Result;

            if (result == "one")
            {
                stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] = 0;
                return await stepContext.NextAsync(await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken));
            }
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"two:{result}") }, cancellationToken);
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> three(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
        }
```

As far as the error is concerned, it seems that the state of "ActiveDialog" has been reset when returning, or ActiveDialog itself has been reset, but I do not know how to solve it.
I want to go back to the previous step and continue with the flow using authentication.
But I don't know the cause of this problem.
I don't know how to solve it.

Please tell me what to do.
Please help me.

Language: C #
Framework: BotFramework v4

Answer (score 0):

Try **-2** if you want to go back 1 step  
 `stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] = (int)stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] - 2;`

And **-1** if you want to return to the same step you are currently in

`stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] = (int)stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] - 1;`

Comment: I tried to solve it, but the same error occurred.  
I'm sorry for telling you so much  
But thank you for telling me.  
Please let me know if you know other solutions.